# Group by por dos columnas con los mismos datos pero cruzadas

Tags: mysql, sql

Hola tengo una tabla con registros de esta manera, y necesito agruparlos por las 2 primeras columnas, siempre que coincidan por parejas:

```
col1      col2      col3
jugador1  jugador2  6
jugador2  jugador1  9
```

Como podria hacer para agruparlas y que me salga algo asi:

```
col1      col2        col3
jugador1  jugador2    15
```

Que las agrupe de esa manera. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2):

El problema básico que hay que atacar es el orden de los valores, una vez ordenados y unificado el criterio, es trivial agrupar y sumar:

```
select  col1,
        col2,
        sum(col3)
        from (  select  case when col1 < col2 then col1 else col2 end as col1,
                        case when col1 < col2 then col2 else col1 end as col2,
                        col3
                        from Tabla
            ) T
        GROUP BY col1, col2
```

Básicamente, en la subconsulta interior ordenamos las columnas, para que sus valores siempre aparezcan igual, es decir, siempre sea `jugador1, jugador2`, resuelto esto simplemente agrupamos por las columnas y sumamos.

Answer (score 2):

No creo que esto sea posible sin información adicional, me explico

```
select a.col1, a.col2, a.col3 + b.col3 as suma
from tabla a
inner join tabla b on a.col1 = b.col2
```

Esto da como resultado

```
col1      col2        col3
jugador2  jugador1    15
jugador1  jugador2    15
```

Si la tabla fuera

```
col1      col2      col3    col4
jugador1  jugador2  6        1
jugador2  jugador1  9        2
```

sería sencillo

```
select a.col1, a.col2, a.col3 + b.col3 as suma
from tabla a
inner join tabla b on a.col1 = b.col2 
where a.col4 = 1
```